# jsf 2 Primefaces commandButton update and actionListener execution order

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

I am a beginner. I would like to know which attribute is executed first when button is clicked.

For example is **bean.method** called first, than update takes place or update happens first than the method is called?

```
p:commandButton update="form" actionListener="#{bean.method}"
```

Comment: See this [Action and ActionListener](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3909382/3102124) for information about `actionListener` or the `action`attribute

Comment: Have a look at the JSF Standard Request-Response Lifecycle: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaqq.html

The actionListener should be invoked in the "Invoke Application" phase and the update happens in the "Render Response" phase.

Comment: @MPirious: since the OP states he/she is a beginner, the concept of 'update' might even beci onfusing. In basic jsf it is called 'render' which is done in the Render Response phase. Updating the model, whichh is a different thing takes place in another earlier phase. A link to the differences in the PrimeFaces vs plain jsf would help to I think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25339056/understanding-process-and-update-attributes-of-primefaces

Comment: The method is executed (assuming that there are no request validation failures) and then the update is carried out

Comment: i read the oracle document about the faces application lifecycle . it helped me to understand the concept more clear